# how i can just choose only 1 radio button in my html

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, forms, radio-button

i have problem in radio button, i need just choosed 1 answer.
but in my codes i can choose all of answer... help me pls

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>A.</strong></span>
                {{Form::textarea('Jawaban_A', Input::old('Jawaban_A'), array('class' => 'form-control' , 'rows' =>
                2))}}
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            {{Form::radio('a_is_benar', 1, Input::old('a_is_benar'), array('id' => 'a_is_benar'))}}
            {{Form::label('a_is_benar', 'Benar', array('class' => 'control-label'));}}
        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Poin</span>
                {{Form::text('Point_Jawaban_A', Input::old('Point_Jawaban_A') ? Input::old('Point_Jawaban_A') : 0,
                array('class' => 'form-control input-lg'))}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>B.</strong></span>
                {{Form::textarea('Jawaban_B', Input::old('Jawaban_B'), array('class' => 'form-control' , 'rows' =>
                2))}}
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            {{Form::radio('b_is_benar', 1, Input::old('b_is_benar'), array('id' => 'b_is_benar'))}}
            {{Form::label('b_is_benar', 'Benar', array('class' => 'control-label'));}}
        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Poin</span>
                {{Form::text('Point_Jawaban_B', Input::old('Point_Jawaban_B') ? Input::old('Point_Jawaban_B') : 0,
                array('class' => 'form-control input-lg'))}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

im using laravel, this is blade view...
maybe have trick for my problem

Comment: all radio name same

Comment: They need to have the same value in `name` attribute

Comment: ty, my problem is done

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a single Form tag.
Then Use Radio Button with same name for Uniquely Selection which you are doing right now.

The Only thing you need to do is to add it inside a single form.